# Arranging from highest coins to lowest coins in leaderboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

There are no errors when I run this code. However, the bot does not send who has the highest balance through leaderboards. It sends who executed the command first. I just wanted to know how I can make the bot return the message through descending order. Database version: 7.0.0. I will provide the code and image. [Image](https://gyazo.com/956cae135ba5752f91a9a3357d0e6fe0)

```
if (args[0] == 'coins') {
   let coins = db.all().filter(a => a.ID.startsWith(`coins_${message.guild.id}`, { sort: '.data'}))
   let content = "";

   for (let i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
   let user = client.users.cache.get(coins[i].ID.split('_')[2]).username

   content += `\`\`\`ini\n[ ${i+1}. ${user} | $${coins[i].data} ]\n\`\`\``

  }

   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(`**${message.guild.name}'s Coin Leaderboard**\n\n${content}`)
      .setThumbnail(URL)
      .setColor(colored[~~(Math.random() * colored.length)])

   message.channel.send(embed)
  }
```

Comment: it would be helpful to mention what database you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify how you want to sort your money inside the `sort()` function.

You can check the options here http://www.egtry.com/javascript/array/sort

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!